# Bad routing with AngularJS and Spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an application with an AngularJS 1.3 front-end and Spring API-REST.

For login I'm using session (no jwt), I'm having this problem:

1. I login to the application.
2. Navigate across the application.
3. When the session is lost, the first request to the backend send me to the login page.
4. I login to the application again, but it redirect me to the last request (the one who kickme out of application), sometimes is an API call, some other is a request to a resources (for example a JavaScript).

I'm not sure how I can avoid that behaviour, this is my Spring Security file:

```xml
<sec:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    <sec:custom-filter ref="captchaFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />

    <sec:custom-filter position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" />

    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession"></sec:session-management>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_switch_user" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="*/app/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/loginFailed" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/public*" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/libs/**" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/fonts/**" access="permitAll" />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <sec:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessDenied"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailureHandler"
        login-processing-url="/login" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />
    <sec:logout />
</sec:http>

<!-- Authentication providers -->

<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="512" />
</bean>

<bean id="authSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
</bean>

<bean id="authFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:defaultFailureUrl="/loginFailed" />

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="jaasAuthProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-target):

> **Setting a Default Post-Login Destination**
>
> If a form login isn’t prompted by an attempt to access a protected resource, the `default-target-url` option comes into play. This is the URL the user will be taken to after successfully logging in, and defaults to "/". You can also configure things so that the user always ends up at this page (regardless of whether the login was "on-demand" or they explicitly chose to log in) by setting the `always-use-default-target` attribute to "true". This is useful if your application always requires that the user starts at a "home" page, for example:
>
> ```xml
> <http pattern="/login.htm*" security="none"/>
> <http use-expressions="false">
>     <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER' />
>     <form-login login-page='/login.htm' default-target-url='/home.htm' always-use-default-target='true' />
> </http>
> ```